# admin_move_table, tables stuck in CLEANUP

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

I'm looking into converting a number of log tables to range partitioning, main purpose is to reduce the size of the database by detaching and archiving historical data. Process looks like:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE('S','T1','', '', '', '', '',
'(ACTION_TIME) (STARTING FROM (''2000-01-01-00.00.00.000000'') ENDING AT (''2029-12-31-23.59.59.999999'') EVERY 1 YEAR)', '', 'COPY_USE_LOAD', 'MOVE' );

...

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE('S','T120','', '', '', '', '',
'(ACTION_TIME) (STARTING FROM (''2000-01-01-00.00.00.000000'') ENDING AT (''2029-12-31-23.59.59.999999'') EVERY 1 YEAR)', '', 'COPY_USE_LOAD', 'MOVE' );
```

For simplicity reasons during this test, I did not do anything about the index on each table (p.k. + ts), they remain in the same tablespace as before. All tables use this tablespace for their indexes

Seems to work alright, although I get a number of mysterious warnings. For every table I get:

```
SQL0206N "STATSPROFTYPE" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

and for some of the temporary tables (which seemed to be tables with quoted names ending with lowercase letters), I got other complaints about runstats.

Did some tests and the tables seemed accessible.

Then I detached old partitions like:

```
for t in $(db2 -x "select rtrim(tabschema) || '.' || rtrim(tabname) from SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS where tabname like '%_LOG' group by tabschema, tabname having COUNT(datapartitionname) > 1"); do
    for p in part{0..18}; do 
        db2 "alter table $t detach partition $p into ${t}_$p"; 
        db2 "drop table ${t}_$p"; 
    done 
    # db2 "reorg table $t";
    db2 "runstats on table $t with distribution and sampled detailed indexes all"
done
```

Still all tables are accessible, but if I query:

```
db2 "SELECT substr(tabschema,1,20), substr(tabname,1,60), substr(VALUE,1,10) FROM SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE WHERE KEY='STATUS'"
```

All tables have a value of CLEANUP. I left it for a couple of hours, there are no activity in the database, but the tables remain the same. On average I probably removed 50% of the rows in these tables, but the size according to:

```
db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, -1)"
...
Parameter Name  : DATABASESIZE
Parameter Value : 769891516416
```

is not reduced.

Due to a lack of ideas, I looped over the tables and reorged each table and all indexes, but it does not seem to change anything.

Is it normal that tables stay in this state for a long period of time? Would it help to wait for CLEANUP, before migrating the next table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the database where the backup origins from had not been  `db2updv115` properly. That in turn lead to that `statsproftype` in `sysibmadm.ADMINTABINFO` did not exist, and the process halted when ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE tried to access that.

After restoring the database, db2updv115 and rebind, ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE seems to work as expected.